# SendKey does not work if previous step has keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL) action

Tags: protractor

I am facing an issue where in my test I need to select multiple rows in the table and click on a button to enter comments for those rows. 
Here is the code I am using for it:

```
pageObj: 
this.Table= element.all(by.repeater("element in elements"));
this.AllRows = this.Table.all(by.css('div.k-grid-content tr'));
this.CommentBtn = element(by.id("add-comments-btn"));
this.AddComments = element(by.id("text-area"));


var SummaryPage = require('./pageObj');
SummaryPage.get(1).click();
browser.actions().mouseMove(SummaryPage .AllRows.get(2)).keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).click().perform(); 
SummaryPage.CommentBtn.click();
SummaryPage.AddComments.click();
SummaryPage.AddComments.sendKeys('comments');
```

Issue: `SummaryPage.AddComments.sendKeys('comments');` does not send anything to the field. 
I tried following also but no success:

```
    SummaryPage.get(1).click();
    browser.actions().mouseMove(SummaryPage .AllRows.get(2)).keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).click().perform(); 
    SummaryPage.CommentBtn.click();
    browser.actions().mouseMove(SummaryPage.AddComments).click().perform();
    SummaryPage.AddComments.sendKeys('comments');
```

if I remove `browser.actions().mouseMove(SummaryPage .AllRows.get(2)).keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).click().perform();` line and select just 1 row everything works fine.

Comment: I am not sure, can you try to put browser.wait or browser.sleep(1000) after each mouse move

Comment: I tried `browser.sleep` as well but it did not helped.

Comment: have you tried by removing this line?    browser.actions().mouseMove(SummaryPage.AddComments).click().perform();

Comment: because once you have clicked the comments button, the comment space to add would have been opened. And after that you just need to send keys. Why are you performing another action.

Comment: @krishnarajanr Because i am not sure if there is problem with the mouse focus shifting to new model.